# Kant's tables, were they ever extended?

Tags: kant

[image: Kant's tables of judgements and categories]

Were Kant's tables of judgements and categories ever extended beyond the 12 sub-classes by anyone?

Kant himself wrote the project would be easy so he didn't bother to extend to sub-sub-categories or -judgements systematically himself, only giving occasional remarks by the half of his Critique of Pure Reason.

I've some ideas how the tables can be extended, but the project seems laborious. Any tips (to eg existing projects) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a very old exercise in revision in :

Stephen Pearl Andrews, 'REVISAL OF KANT'S CATEGORIES', The Journal of Speculative Philosophy, Vol. 8, No. 3 (July, 1874), pp. 268-275.

But now, doesn't Kant himself revise the categories in the sense of producing two different sets ? There is the set tabulated in the Transcendental Analytic, Bk I, Section 3, 'On the pure concepts of the categories of the understanding or categories'. (Kant, Critique of Pure Reason, tr. P. Guyer & Allen Wood, Cambridge : CUP, 2000 : 210-18.)

There is also the set expounded in the Schematism of the Transcendental Analytic, Bk II, ch. 1, 'On the Schematism of pure concepts of the understanding'. (Kant, Critique of Pure Reason, tr. P. Guyer & Allen Wood, Cambridge : CUP, 2000 : 271-7.)

To follow up on this, see T. K. Seung, 'Kant's Conception of the Categories
', The Review of Metaphysics, Vol. 43, No. 1 (Sep., 1989), pp. 107-132.